# Phonegap page has wrong rotation, shows as portrait in landscape mode

Tags: html, ipad, cordova, screen-orientation

I have a (simple) web page packed in a phonegap app. If I start the app it shows the page in portrait direction with landscape page width. So the text starts left bottom to left top. On the right I have a gap where the page should end.

This is what I see:

[image]

Supported orientations are landscape left and right in my `...-Info.plist`:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
</array>
```

On my iPad I locked the screen rotate. The launch image shows up correct in landscape.

The page is designed to fit into landscape with fixed sizes. This is my viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

and the page has the correct width for landscape but it is turned around. I can scroll up and down. The ipad status bar jumps from the top to the left after app start.

**UPDATE**

I change target device to iPad only and allowed orientation to Landscape Left only now the status bar is on the top where it needs to be. Page is still turned... I also tried to make a [simple page version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999435/phonegap-ipad-no-rotation-at-all) that should rotate what did not work either.

**Update 2**

In `Classes/MainViewController.m` I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: what happens when you rotate your app to portrait and then again to landscape ?

Comment: Checkt the root controller - shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, if its allow the root view rotation?

Comment: @Tom That's it! Can you post it as an answer? So I can give you some reputation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the root Controller - shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, allow rotation for certain orientation. Hope it helps.

For example `return true` in `Classes/MainViewController.m`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354910/tom)'s reply to the question, I thought I'd share a solution for those rebuilding an app with an older version of XCode and iOS.  I don't recall the older versions I had, but I am now on XCode 4.6.1 using a Base SDK of iOS 6.1.  I'm sure I was using a Base SDK of iOS 5.x previously.

I have replaced it with the following line:

```
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
```

...with the line below, and the orientation is corrected:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=720,maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

and for more read [this page](http://www.allenpike.com/2010/choosing-a-viewport-for-ipad-sites/)

Comment: I have a viewport with `width=device-width`. I added it to my question.