# Media query not working with Landscape orientation

Tags: css, media-queries

For my CSS media queries I've set it up mobile first which deals with all the overall styling.

I then have:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 790px) {
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 990px) {
}
```

and I've added in

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 520px) {
}
```

which deals with the CSS changes when the smart phone is turned round to landscape mode, but it doesn't seem to work, am I writing the landscape media query wrong?

Comment: Which device are you testing it on? iPhone5 has a max-width of 560px.

Comment: Ive got a iPhone 4S which im testing it on

Comment: It could be that styles are conflicting. Can you post a link we can tet?

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue: my iPod/iPhone devices were detected as portrait orientation even when rotated.

I managed to resolve that with the following media query:

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 4/3) 
{*your styles here*}
```

If you want to target any case when width is greater than height, I think something like (min-aspect-ratio: 101/100) or something like this might work. However, for current devices 4/3 is sufficient, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you need aspect ratio for landscape, I think `min-aspect-ratio: 1` suffices ... and therefore `max-aspect-ratio: 1` for portrait.

But, even when the CSS is correct, there's an additional step required for a Cordova / PhoneGap app: [Why doesn't my Cordova/PhoneGap iOS app rotate when the device rotates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999435/why-doesnt-my-cordova-phonegap-ios-app-rotate-when-the-device-rotates/)

I found this StackOverflow item before that one, so perhaps others will also find a cross-link useful.