# Visual Studio Apache Cordova - IOS build rotation issue

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I'm a starter in writing app code in Visual Studio 2013 Community Apache Cordova and have managed to connect VS2013 with my Mac. Once I have gone through the process of building the app in VS and on my Mac and installing in on my iPhone, I open it up and it won't rotate. It doesn't rotate for a number of basic apps that I've written nor does it rotate if I build the default new project "Hello, your application is ready!" app.

I have done some research and tried changing the config.xml "Orientation" preference to "both", through the code window and also in the designer window but that doesn't change anything. I've also noticed that adding in a "BackgroundColor" preference doesn't work either.

Does anyone know if I may have configured something incorrectly or perhaps need to add something to my code?

All the HTML, JS and CSS that I've written seems to work okay (with the exception of trying to link URLs to the Safari Browser but that's another issue).

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same issues. I tried finding some settings to fix that in the config.xml, but was not successful. I have resolved myself to just opening the iOS project in XCode and changing a few things:

- Device Orientation: no matter the config.xml setting, its always only Portrait.  I click-check the other 3 orientations.
- Team: I have multiple developer profiles, and I need to choose correct one here.
- Bundle Identifier. I screwed up one project, and have different case for iOS and Android. I leave the VS one as the Android one, so I can build completely correct for Android. Since I know I have to go to XCode for iOS anyway, I change the bundle identifier here.

You can find the project using Finder at ~/remote-builds/builds/9999/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/*.xcodeproj, where 9999 is the build number, though not necessarily the latest, largest number, but the latest datetime of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to Greg's answer in this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999435/why-doesnt-my-cordova-phonegap-ios-app-rotate-when-the-device-rotates) as an alternative solution.