# Cordova 5 build command is deleting iOS device orientation settings

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, cordova-5.0.0

With Cordova 5.1.1, when executing "cordova build ios", any device orientation settings previously selected in the XCode project are deleted leaving the orientation settings checkboxes unselected.

While the "orientation" config preference may provide a means of forcing orientation, I need to be able to set different orientation preferences for the iPad and iPhone.

All previous Cordova versions (below 5) respected those settings. Any ideas?

Using XCode 6.3.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

According to [@Abhinav Gujjar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154353/abhinav-gujjar) the issue causing `cordova prepare` to overwrite manual changes made to orientation settings in the .plist has been fixed. However, AFAIK there's still no way to set different orientation preferences for iPad vs iPhone in the config.xml, so the answer below stands.

**UPDATE**:

I created the plugin [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config), which wraps up the hook below and means platform-specific custom config blocks (such as these orientation settings) can be defined in config.xml. So you can use the plugin rather than need to manually create the hook below.

---

This was introduced in the Cordova 5.0.0 CLI - [see here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8953).

In the meantime, I've been using an after_prepare hook as a workaround. Just place the following in `<your_project>/hooks/after_prepare/some_file.js` and change the orientation settings as appropriate:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Set support for all orienations in iOS .plist - workaround for this cordova bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8953
var platforms = process.env.CORDOVA_PLATFORMS.split(',');
platforms.forEach(function(p) {
    if (p == "ios") {
        var fs = require('fs'),
            plist = require('plist'),
            xmlParser = new require('xml2js').Parser(),
            plistPath = '',
            configPath = 'config.xml';
        // Construct plist path.
        if (fs.existsSync(configPath)) {
            var configContent = fs.readFileSync(configPath);
            // Callback is synchronous.
            xmlParser.parseString(configContent, function (err, result) {
                var name = result.widget.name;
                plistPath = 'platforms/ios/' + name + '/' + name + '-Info.plist';
            });
        }
        // Change plist and write.
        if (fs.existsSync(plistPath)) {
            var pl = plist.parseFileSync(plistPath);
            configure(pl);
            fs.writeFileSync(plistPath, plist.build(pl).toString());
        }
        process.exit();
    }
});
function configure(plist) {
    var iPhoneOrientations = [
        'UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft',
        'UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight',
        'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait',
        'UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown'
    ];
    var iPadOrientations = [
            'UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft',
            'UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight',
            'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait',
            'UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown'
    ];
    plist["UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"] = iPhoneOrientations;
    plist["UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad"] = iPadOrientations;
}
```

Note: you'll need to install the plist and xml2js node modules if you don't already have them.

Comment: This solution works perfectly Dave. At first I installed plist and xml2js without sudo and I was having problems. Once I uninstalled both and reinstalled with sudo, all worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

IF you want to, you can to it programmatically on the JS side.

> For iOS, orientation can be programmatically controlled by defining a
>   javascript callback on window

```
/** 
// @param {Number} degree - UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait: 0,
// UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight: 90, 
// UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft: -90,     
// UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown: 180
* @returns {Boolean} Indicating if rotation should be allowed.
*/
function shouldRotateToOrientation(degrees) {
     return true;
}
```

Set allowed orientations in your `config.xml` file

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
</platform>
```

And add the `shouldRotateToOrientation(degrees)`

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    window.shouldRotateToOrientation = function(degrees) {
        //if device an iPad ?
        if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ) {
            return true;
        } 
        //else if device an iPhone ?
        else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
            if (degrees == 0) { //orientation is portrait
              return true;
            }
            return false; //refuse all other orientations for iPhone
        }
        return true;
    };
}
```

Comment: And where do you throw this code? Just in the AngularJS app's index.html file?

Comment: Thanks very much for following up. I had a heck of a time with this.  I upgraded the version of Cordova's iOS plugin in my app, and it broke the orientation rotation - until this, at least.

Comment: works for me - one thing, perhaps you could put your ifs on the outside, ie set the callback according to device, that way its only doing the match once - thanks very much btw, it was a frustration

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed and you can now specify orientation as 'all' in config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
      <preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
</platform>
```

[Docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/blob/676f107163d17c70cfa528ed13583dc8dcd8f5d2/docs/en/edge/config_ref/index.md#multi-platform-preferences)

Comment: The bug causing orientation preferences to be overwritten may have been fixed, but the original question asked " I need to be able to set different orientation preferences for the iPad and iPhone" and AFAIK this is still not possible to do using settings in the config.xml

Comment: You're right - OP does want different specs for device types. I arrived here cause it was locking me to portrait. Guess I got excited that this was fixed.

Comment: Still, good to know that the bug got fixed - thanks for the update :-)

Comment: unfortunately this is now broken in cordova 5.4: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9975